# Unexpected behaviour with Faraday::ConnectionFailed

Tags: ruby, api, http, faraday

I'm writing a client for an API that rescue from `Faraday::ConnectionFailed` and `Faraday::TimeoutError` to retry the same method `MAX_RETRIES` times.

This is the main method involved:

```
def benchmark_request(path)
  retries ||= 0
  request_start_time = Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC)

  response = yield

  total_request_seconds = (Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC) - request_start_time)
  Rails.logger.info "client request took (#{total_request_seconds}s): #{ENV['API_PATH_PREFIX']}#{path}"

  response
rescue Faraday::ConnectionFailed, Faraday::TimeoutError => e
  retries += 1
  retry if retries <= MAX_RETRIES
end
```

the method calling that is:

```
 def get(path, params = {})
   benchmark_request(path) { token.get("#{ENV['API_PATH_PREFIX']}#{path}", params) }
 end
```

`token.get` comes from the `oauth2` gem which is using `Faraday`

Here's the fun bit.
I wrote 2 specs, 1 for each exception I want to handle.

```
context 'when the endpoint raises a ConnectionFailed' do
  let(:token_expires_at) { 1.hour.from_now.to_i }
  let(:response_body) { '' }
  let(:response_status) { 200 }

  before do
    allow(token).to receive(:get).and_raise(Faraday::ConnectionFailed)
    described_class.get(api_endpoint)
  end

  it 'is called MAX_RETRIES times' do
    expect(token).to have_received(:get).exactly(3).times
  end
end

context 'when the endpoint raises a TimeoutError' do
  let(:token_expires_at) { 1.hour.from_now.to_i }
  let(:response_body) { '' }
  let(:response_status) { 200 }

  before do
    allow(token).to receive(:get).and_raise(Faraday::TimeoutError)
    described_class.get(api_endpoint)
  end

  it 'is called MAX_RETRIES times' do
    expect(token).to have_received(:get).exactly(3).times
  end
end
```

The test testing `ConnectionFailed` fails, the test testing `TimeoutError` is green.
The exception raised is:

```
1) Client::Base.get when the endpoint raises a ConnectionFailed is called MAX_RETRIES times
 Failure/Error: token.get(path, params)

 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)
 # /home/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/faraday-0.15.4/lib/faraday/error.rb:7:in `initialize'
 # ./app/lib/client/base.rb:13:in `get'
 # ./spec/lib/client/base_spec.rb:111:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Which apparently is about how the Exception is initialized.

Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
before do
   allow(token).to receive(:get).and_raise(Faraday::TimeoutError, 'execution expired')
  described_class.get(api_endpoint)
end
```

I solved this by passing a [second argument](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/raising-an-error) to the `and_raise` method. I think it's because Faraday has slightly different exception classes.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because Farady::ConnectionFailed inherits from Faraday::Error class which in its `def initialize` requires at least one argument. Check the source [here (Error)](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/main/lib/faraday/error.rb#L9) and [here (ConnectionFailed)](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/main/lib/faraday/error.rb#L137).

TimeoutError works because it has default value set for `exc` to `"timeout"` [here](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/main/lib/faraday/error.rb#L123).

It was difficult to spot on a first glance and I totally understand you that you were lost as well.

As @MikeRogers0 mentioned in his solution, you have to use second argument in `and_raise`.

I hope you will find this answer helpful.